# How to implement Change Data Capture (CDC) using apache spark and kafka?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-kafka, cdc

I am using spark-sql-2.4.1v with java 1.8. and kafka versions spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.11_2.4.3 and kafka-clients_0.10.0.0.

I need to join streaming data with meta-data which is stored in RDS.
but RDS meta data could be added/changed.

If I read and load RDS table data in application , it would be stale for joining with streaming data.

I  understood ,need to use Change Data Capture (CDC).
How can I implement Change Data Capture (CDC) in my scenario?

any clues or sample way to implement Change Data Capture (CDC) ?

thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3):

You can stream a database into Kafka so that the contents of a table plus every subsequent change is available on a Kafka topic. From here it can be used in stream processing.

You can do CDC in two different ways:

- Query-based: poll the database for changes, using Kafka Connect JDBC Source
- Log-based: extract changes from the database's transaction log using e.g. Debezium

For more details and examples see http://rmoff.dev/ksny19-no-more-silos

Comment: I don't know about spark stream but Kafka Streams and KSQL both support stream-stream joins. See https://kafka-tutorials.confluent.io/join-a-stream-to-a-stream/ksql.html